# Making a object with soft and rigid body physics

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, soft-body

I'm a bit stumped on how I can do something like this. I'm making a whip from Steven Universe and I want to know if I can somehow designate parts of the object as vertex groups that are rigid bodies, and other parts that are soft bodies.

What I basically mean, is that I want to know if I can use vertex groups to separate parts of my whip into being soft bodied (the whip section) or rigid bodied (handle, tip and such)

Here's a very quickly done render of my object for reference.

[image: Amethyst Whip Steven Universe]

Comment: Have you tried making the object a soft body and making the handle a vertex painted area?